# No links are working on my website home page

Tags: wordpress

Non of the links are not working on my wordpress website homepage i have checked everything but still they unclickable.

URL: https://chaseframing.ca/

Comment: In your `body` tas has a lodder `div`, and it's clss is `hourglass-loader loader-removed`. Check in JS files after load complete page this class will remove. After this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to change css of the body #load element

```
body #load 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

so you need to remove z-index or set lower value in the z-index

check screenshot for more details: http://prntscr.com/nlyuiq

Let me know it's help or not.

Comment: Please let me know answer is helpful or not

Comment: Okay Great @Farrukh and let me know if anything need from my side.